# Converting project from Swift 2.3 to Swift 3.0 - Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'UITextField' and 'Bool'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I had a running project on Swift 2.3 with no errors. I have updated this project to Swift 3.0 and I solved all issues but not this one:

The error message is following: **Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'UITextField' and 'Bool'**

```
func textFieldShouldClear(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    // called when clear button pressed. return NO to ignore (no notifications)

    if textField == true {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    return true
}
```

I tried to find a solution here but nothing covering swift 3.0.
Anyone any idea?

Thanks you.

Olli

Comment: What do you want to express semantically with `if textField == true`?

Comment: The error is pretty clear, you can't compare UITextField to Bool type, it doesn't make any sense. I am not sure what is that piece of code supposed to do, didn't you want to check it passed textfield is specific one you have store in your property somewhere?

Comment: Thank you all for your comment, which brought me on the correct way. Finally got the same solution as shallowThought suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing an `UITextField` with `Bool`, which is not possible, as you can compare only objects of the same type using the `==` operator.

Simply remofe the `if` clause:

```
func textFieldShouldClear(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    tableView.reloadData()
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're trying to see if the textfield is empty or not. You can achieve it by doing so :

```
func textFieldShouldClear(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    // called when clear button pressed. return NO to ignore (no notifications)

    if textField.hasText {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    return true
}
```